# NSArray assignments causes "Multiple unsequenced modifications"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsarray, compiler-warnings

I'm assigning elements to an array at compile time (Xcode). The compiler warning ("Multiple unsequenced modifications") implies that the compiler might not compute the assignments in the same order as the elements are listed.

Simplified code example (I'm actually using a macro to assign `array1` elements):

```
- (void)arrayAssignmentTest
{
    int x = 0;

    // The compiler warning implies that I cannot rely on
    // the order the compiler executes the assignments.
    NSArray *array1 = @[
        @(x++),  // @(0) <-- WARNING: Multiple unsequenced modifications to 'x'
        @(x++),  // @(1)
        @(x++),  // @(2)
    ];

    // But, there's no warning here, so I assume I can rely on
    // the order in which the compiler executes these assignments.
    NSArray *array2 = @[
        myFunction(),   // @(0)
        myFunction(),   // @(1)
        myFunction(),   // @(2)
    ];
}

NSNumber *myFunction()
{
    static int x = 0;
    return @(x++);
}
```

The compiler is warning about `array1` assignments, but it doesn't it warn about `array2`.

Why does the compiler treat `array1` differently from `array2`, and is there a better way to tell the compiler to assemble the `array1` elements in order instead of using a separate function or method as for `array2`?

Comment: [Unsequenced modifications](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=unsequenced+modifications) search query on SO - there's a lot of resources to learn from & [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) @ Wikipedia.

Comment: @zrzka thank you for the link.  I did search SO before posting, but the Wikipedia article was new to me -- and it mentions "ambiguity" as the root cause,.  However, my question concerns the compiler.  What's ambiguous about my arrays?  Why can't the compiler assign the elements is the order they are given in my code?

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C - simply put - backward compatible extensions to C. [C11 standard draft](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). **Annex C** contains a list of sequence points. **5.1.2.3 Program execution** - par 2, 3 - side effects & sequences. **6.5. Expressions** - par 2 - undefined behavior b/o unsequenced side effects, par 3 - side effects & value computations of subexpressions are unsequenced, etc. It's really all about side effects & sequence points and you should know your tools (read standard).

Comment: If you need more examples - check the [clang tests](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/master/clang/test), mainly [Sema/warn-unsequenced.c](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/clang/test/Sema/warn-unsequenced.c). These tests are easily readable and contains lot of valuable information.